# Bind zones good practices

Tags: dns, bind, records, nameservers, zones

I'm relatively new to Bind/DNS zones but have been reading a lot into it lately and was passed a link to check the DNS out.  I ran the checks which can be seen via: http://intodns.com/empireconqueror.com

The issue is there seems to be a lot of issues still wrong with the zone, there seems to be no information regarding those errors on the Internet so I come here seeking help.

My options are as follows:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    //forwarders {
    //      199.115.230.239;
    //};

    allow-query {
            any;
    };

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };

    allow-recursion { localhost; };
};
```

And for the actual zone options:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";

view "external-in" in {
    match-clients { any; };
    allow-query { none; };
    allow-query-cache { none; };
    recursion no;
    additional-from-auth yes;
    additional-from-cache yes;

    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
};
```

Here's a master zone example:

```
zone "empireconqueror.com" {
    type master;
    file "/ect/bind/db.empireconqueror.com";
};
```

Database file:

```
$TTL    86400
$ORIGIN empireconqueror.com.
@       IN      SOA     ns2.webserverhome.com. hostmaster.empireconqueror.com. (
                          2002022401
                          28800
                          7200
                          864000
                          86400
                         )
; Root site
    IN      A       199.115.230.240

; Nameservers
    IN      NS      ns1.webserverhome.com.
    IN      NS      ns2.webserverhome.com.

; Aliases
www     IN      CNAME   empireconqueror.com.
fb      IN      CNAME   empireconqueror.com.
mail    IN      CNAME   ghs.google.com.

; MX Records
    IN      MX      1       aspmx.l.google.com.
    IN      MX      5       alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
    IN      MX      5       alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
    IN      MX      10      aspmx2.googlemail.com.
    IN      MX      10      aspmx3.googlemail.com.
```

Many thanks for helping out,
Shaun

Comment: the problem is that that ns1.webserverhome.com and n2.webserverhome.com doesn't seem to exist in a zone file, or answer.  You will need to fix that problem first.  if you own webserverhome.com  as well, you need to go to registrar and add DNS glue records or build NS based on webserverhome.com). Without them, you cannot reference the nameservers from other zones.

Comment: Hello Doon, I do also own the webserverhome.com domain and have glued the A records for ns1 and ns2 with a records for the relevant IP's.

Comment: well now ns[12].webserverhome.com  resolve.  But in looking at empireconqueror.com, it is pointing to ns[12].svnr.net.

Comment: Doon, you're right buddy!  I got the reverse zone mixed up with the other master zones and didn't register the name servers within it.  Cheers for pointing me in the right direction :)  Post the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that that ns1.webserverhome.com and n2.webserverhome.com doesn't seem to exist in a zone file, or answer. You will need to fix that problem first. if you own webserverhome.com as well, you need to go to registrar and add DNS glue records or build NS based on webserverhome.com). Without them, you cannot reference the nameservers from other zones.